# Remake of this regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, forms

I have this regular expression to help me validate a form input.

```
var nrExp = /^\d{6}\-\d{4}$/;
```

This allows only 10 digits, where the last 4 digits are separated with a "minus sign".

```
    012345-6789
```

I need to make it also allow it without the minus-sign AND with a space instead of a minus-sign:

```
   0123456789
   012345 6789
```

How can I remake this regexp to allow what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure. You just want to make the minus optional, along with a couple of other characters.

Try this one:

```
var nrExp = /^\d{6}(\-| )?\d{4}$/;
```

Notice the `?` after the `(\-| )`. This allows that match portion to be optional.

Comment: Should work, but it's kinda ugly.  (1) The `-` doesn't need escaping outside a `[]` block at all.  (2) If you're matching one of two possible chars, rather than strings, `[- ]` is a better fit than `(\-| )` (and doesn't create a capture group, unlike your example).

Comment: @cHao Thanks for the advice. Consider though, that he may want to add other characters in the future. I know that it will work with the character class as well, I'm just so used to using multi-character separators for everything, I tend to use `()` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
/^\d{6}[- ]?\d{4}$/
```

You don't need to escape the minus sign inside the brackets, as it does not give a range.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d{6}[ \-]?\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

`var nrExp = /^\d{6}\[\- ]?\d{4}$/;`

That should do it - either a blank space or a dash, made optional by the ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /^\d{6}[\- ]?\d{4}$/
console.log(re.test('012345-6789'));
console.log(re.test('012345 6789'));
console.log(re.test('0123456789'));
```